# why does command prompt throw error when trying to access a file and the path is already set?

Tags: python-3.x

(base) C:\Users\User 1\Documents\labelImg-master>ppyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
'C:/Users/User' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Because there is a space between `User` and `1`

Comment: Because of the space. Looks like a bug

Comment: Can generally be fixed by putting " " around it